# Shibboleth Site Can't be Reached After Login

Tags: asp-classic, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I have successfully, or so I thought, connected up to our IDP for single sign on with shibboleth. I went to the Shibboleth test login page and was prompted by our IDP to login. Once I logged in, it gave me an error saying that the site can't be reached and that the server IP address could not be found. I have tried going to the logout and status pages and get that same error. I am not seeing anything in the shibd logs that indicate any errors. I have tried resetting my shibboleth daemon and my IIS and still am getting the same error.

Could this be something to do with my shibboleth2.xml configuration? I am not sure how the server IP address would be affected by this.

I can provide any needed information you may need!

Answer (score 0):

If your secured url is `https://local-or-some-domain/secure`, when you hit that URL and you are taken to idP, after successful login you are taken back to the same URL but the browser says nothing found.

If above is your scenario then congratulations, you have successfully integrated the shibboleth SP with idP. Most of the time error occurs because there is no page hosted to the URL we secured.

If above is not your scenario then you may want to elaborate little more.